# Ordered Doubly Linked List

Tags: python, doubly-linked-list

Ok A question from assignment says to create an ordered doubly linked list...such that each object with lexicographically smaller name comes "Before" the other One...Like names in a Dictionary...also objects with same name can be arranged in any order...

To link two objects I have `setBefore()` and `setAfter()` method...
and I have done this much...but still don't know where I'm doing wrong..may be a little guidance from you guys can help me...

`atMe` is an object that is already present in the doubly linked list and `newFrob` is an object to be inserted...

```
def insert(atMe, newFrob):
    if newFrob.myName() < atMe.myName():
        if atMe.getBefore() == None:
            atMe.setBefore(newFrob)
            newFrob.setAfter(atMe)
        elif atMe.getBefore().myName()<newFrob.myName():
            atMe.getBefore().setAfter(newFrob)
            newFrob.setBefore(atMe.getBefore)
            atMe.setBefore(newFrob)
            newFrob.setAfter(atMe)
        else:
            insert(atMe.getBefore(),newFrob)

    elif newFrob.myName() > atMe.myName():
        if atMe.getAfter() == None:
            atMe.setAfter(newFrob)
            newFrob.setBefore(atMe)
        elif atMe.getAfter().myName()>newFrob.myName():
            atMe.getAfter().setBefore(newFrob)
            newFrob.setAfter(atMe.getAfter)
            atMe.setAfter(newFrob)
            newFrob.setBefore(atMe)
        else:
            insert(atMe.getAfter(),newFrob)

    elif newFrob.myName()==atMe.myName():
        if atMe.getAfter() != None:
            newFrob.setAfter(atMe.getAfter())
        newFrob.setBefore(atMe)
        if atMe.getAfter() != None:
            atMe.getAfter().setBefore(newFrob)
        atMe.setAfter(newFrob)
```

And this is the Frob Class to be used...

```
class Frob(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.before = None
        self.after = None
    def setBefore(self, before):
        self.before = before
    def setAfter(self, after):
        self.after = after
    def getBefore(self):
        return self.before
    def getAfter(self):
        return self.after
    def myName(self):
        return self.name
```

where Before and After are links to left and right objects in double linked list...
objects from this class are to be inserted to double linked list...

Example:

```
a=Frob('foo')
b=Frob('bar')
c=Frob('frob')
d=Frob('code')

code                             output
insert(a,b)                   bar->foo
insert(a,c)                   bar->foo->frob
insert(b,d)                   bar->code->foo->frob
```

now suppose

```
code                             output
insert(b,Frob('code'))        bar->code->code->foo->frob
```

Comment: @downvoters: Please explain. As I can see, OP had clearly laid down the question, presented his best effort and still he cannot find a solution and would require help. He may not be quite apt with Python but we should help him out instead of downvoting.

Comment: please explain what you mean _exactly_ by a `Ordered Doubly Linked List`? explain how it should work, what methods it should implement... etc etc...

Comment: @eumiro thanks...but still no improvement...

Comment: what you described is a normal linked-list, where are the 'ordered' and 'double' parts coming from?

Comment: @abhijit thanks...
I think I am missing some boundry conditions...and yes I am not good at python just started it 3-4 months ago...

Comment: I suggest you look through some related posts that can all be found to your right under 'related' i will post some here for you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611254/sorted-doubly-linked-list-python?rq=1  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352976/inserting-in-the-middle-of-a-doubly-linked-list-python?rq=1

Comment: I do not see anything particularly incorrect about your solution. In my experience, it is somewhat odd to have the insert function traverse the list recursively like this, but there is nothing _wrong_ with doing it that way. Can you tell us about a problem you are having? Like an example of a series of inserts after which the list is wrong?

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611254/sorted-doubly-linked-list-python  Helps you, it was asked before and its very similar to your question.

Comment: @ken telling the truth...I was submitting it on the grader but got wrong answers everytime...but I was not able to get the reason...
It works well for test conditions...
and to all who think I want you to do my homework...I am asking it after I have no time left to submit it...[I also do not like cheating]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in this line (and an equivalent one when you're moving the other direction):

```
newFrob.setBefore(atMe.getBefore)
```

You're missing a set of parentheses after `atMe.getBefore`, so you end up passing the bound method itself to `newFrob.setBefore` rather than the value that would be returned by that method. This is an easy typo to make, so I wouldn't feel too bad about missing it on your assignment.

I found the error by trying the following sequence of inserts and inspecting the values (I've summarized the ones that worked OK with comments):

```
>>> a = Frob("a")
>>> b = Frob("b")
>>> c = Frob("c")
>>> d = Frob("d")
>>> insert(a, b) # list is a<->b
>>> insert(a, d) # list is a<->b<->d
>>> insert(a, c) # list is a<->b<->c->?
>>> c.getAfter()
<bound method Frob.getAfter of <__main__.Frob object at 0x000000000318EBA8>>
```

That object mentioned at the end is `b`, which lead me to find the error in the code.